# Can I use command blocks to automatically spawn all filled maps that exist in my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have used an online map-art creator to create map art. I downloaded the map files and there are a total of 134.
I know that I can get maps by using the following command:

```
/give [playername | @p] minecraft:filled_map [amount_of_maps] [map_number]
```

But is there perhaps a way to tell a command block to give me all the maps? For example it puts map 1 in a chest, then map 2, map 3 and so on.
Or is the only way to get all 134 maps by repeatedly using the command?